Make Graphics.DrawLine draw "bigger pixels" when using ScaleTransform
I need to create a little image viewer that allows me to select a pixel-perfect position on a pasted image. That position is marked with an X around the marked pixel, along with some other graphics.
For better usability, I am able to zoom into the image. The X needs to zoom too, of course. But I want the X to look like it's painted onto the image and zoom with it. For example, when selecting pixel (10, 10) in this checkerboard:

But simply using Graphics.ScaleTransform and then .DrawLine results in this:

Here's the code that produced this output:
Public Class Form1

    Dim ZoomFactor As Integer = 20
    Dim MarkedX As Integer = 10
    Dim MarkedY As Integer = 10

    Dim DisplayWhatIWant As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Toggle() Handles Me.MouseDown, Me.Load
        DisplayWhatIWant = Not DisplayWhatIWant
        Text = If(DisplayWhatIWant, "What I want", "What happens instead")
        Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(ZoomFactor, ZoomFactor)

        ' Draw the image
        Using CheckerboardBipm As New Bitmap("D:\200x200Checkerboard.png")
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(CheckerboardBipm, 0, 0, CheckerboardBipm.Width, CheckerboardBipm.Height)
        End Using

        If DisplayWhatIWant Then
            Using TempBitmap As New Bitmap(50 * ZoomFactor, 50 * ZoomFactor, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                Using g = Graphics.FromImage(TempBitmap)
                    g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None
                    g.Clear(Color.Transparent)
                    ' Draw the lines unscaled to a temporary bitmap...
                    DrawCross(g)
                End Using
                ' ... then draw the bitmap scaled
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(TempBitmap, 0, 0, TempBitmap.Width, TempBitmap.Height)
            End Using
        Else
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None
            ' Draw the lines scaled directly
            DrawCross(e.Graphics)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DrawCross(g As Graphics)
        Const MarkerSize = 5
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, MarkedX - 1, MarkedY - 1, MarkedX - MarkerSize, MarkedY - MarkerSize)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, MarkedX - 1, MarkedY + 1, MarkedX - MarkerSize, MarkedY + MarkerSize)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, MarkedX + 1, MarkedY - 1, MarkedX + MarkerSize, MarkedY - MarkerSize)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, MarkedX + 1, MarkedY + 1, MarkedX + MarkerSize, MarkedY + MarkerSize)
    End Sub

End Class

And the 200x200Checkerboard.png used in the example:

I created the "What I want" output by drawing the lines unscaled to a temporary bitmap and then drawing it scaled on top of the image. But I want to avoid that because it makes things a lot more complicated.
Is there a way of directly rendering lines "scaled up" in this way?

Probably not directly, but for 45° lines, it shouldn't be too hard to draw a series of squares.

Yep, but the actual graphics I want to draw are more complicated than just that.
